# Passing a quoted string to a function inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SE_VALOR] (@valor int, @verd char(20), @fals char(20))
RETURNS char(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @resposta char(20)
    ---Check for unit, if meters(MT), convert it to feet(FT)
    IF @valor=1
        BEGIN
            set @resposta = @verd
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @resposta =@fals
    END
RETURN( @resposta   )
END
```

And then I have this stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_pn_FichaTecnica_Motor_Web]
@IDVersao int

AS

DECLARE @Comando nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @DIESEL varchar(10)
DECLARE @GASOLINA varchar(10)

SET @DIESEL = 'Diesel'
SET @GASOLINA = 'Gasolina'

--

set @Comando = 'SELECT somefield1, somefield2, somefield3,
                dbo.SE_VALOR(TblMotor.TipoInjeccao,@DIESEL,@GASOLINA) AS TipoInjeccao
                FROM sometable
                WHERE IDVersao = @IDVersao'

EXEC sp_executesql @Comando, N'@IDVersao int, @DIESEL varchar(10),@GASOLINA varchar(10)',@IDVersao,@DIESEL,@GASOLINA
print(@Comando)
```

How can I pass the vars @DIESEL and @GASOLINA without giving me errors?

If I try to execute the SP with:

```
exec SP_pn_FichaTecnica_Motor_Web 27828
```

I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
>   Incorrect syntax near

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your problem, you wanted to pass constants as constants, not as parameters.
In this case:

```
set @Comando = 'SELECT somefield1, somefield2, somefield3,
            dbo.SE_VALOR(TblMotor.TipoInjeccao,''Diesel'',''Gasolina'') AS TipoInjeccao
            FROM sometable
            WHERE IDVersao = @IDVersao'

EXEC sp_executesql @Comando, N'@IDVersao int',@IDVersao
```

In other words, you just need to double the single quote.

Comment: Hi @Naomi! Tried that. When executing the stored procedure it return the same error above. :(

Comment: Can you please post the exact error and exact code you tried? I believe the above should work fine. Are you sure you use two single quotes and not 1 double quote?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help. I assigned the useful answer to @Naomi because the double quote worked.
But the real problem was the size of the var @Comando.
I had it defined as:

```
DECLARE @Comando nvarchar(4000)
```

but realized that the query was exceding this value, so changing it to:

```
DECLARE @Comando nvarchar(max)
```

solved my problem.

Hope this helps other people. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error you're getting (complete error)? From the first glance your code is OK (except for wrongly using sp_ prefix for your own stored procedure - this prefix is reserved for system stored procedures and you should try to use anything else, say, sp without _).

Comment: Changed sp_ to usp_ on all my user stored procedures :)

Comment: For simplicity of this post, I downsized the query I'm using, but it's a mile long.
The error is always:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32 Incorrect syntax near
and then it prints the query stopping at a left outter join

Comment: Looks like the error may be something else - remove for now the call to the function and re-try without it.

Answer (score 0):

For input parameters, you can just put them directly in your query, but you may want to escape the `'` character by replacing it with `''`.

The output of your SP should be the output parameter, for example:

```
SET @DIESEL = (REPLACE (@DIESEL, '''', ''''''))
SET @GASOLINA = (REPLACE (@GASOLINA, '''', ''''''))
SET @IDVersao = (REPLACE (@IDVersao, '''', ''''''))

set @Comando = 'SELECT @myOutput = 
            dbo.SE_VALOR(TblMotor.TipoInjeccao,'+@DIESEL+','+@GASOLINA+') AS TipoInjeccao
            FROM sometable
            WHERE IDVersao = '+@IDVersao+''

EXEC sp_executesql @Comando, N'@myOutput CHAR(20) OUTPUT', @myOutput OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @Comando = 'SELECT somefield1, somefield2, somefield3,
                dbo.SE_VALOR(TblMotor.TipoInjeccao,@DIESEL,@GASOLINA) AS TipoInjeccao
                FROM sometable
                WHERE IDVersao = @IDVersao'
```

change it to

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
set @Comando = "SELECT somefield1, somefield2, somefield3,
                dbo.SE_VALOR(TblMotor.TipoInjeccao,@DIESEL,@GASOLINA) AS TipoInjeccao
                FROM sometable
                WHERE IDVersao = @IDVersao"
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```